# Difference between plot and scatter matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, scatter-plot

Consider the following data points and plots

```
a = randi(50,1,200);
b = randi(50,1,200);
figure;scatter(a,b,'.')
figure;plot(a,b,'.')
```

When we run the following code , we receive exactly the same plots for a against b , my question is why should we even use or to rephrase again in what conditions `scatter` plot has advantage over `plot` function ? because `plot` seem to have more formatting options that the `scatter` function

Comment: `plot` has a number of formatting options but they are typically suited to data series of the same type, as the formatting will be applied uniformly to all the data points. Also, `plot` joins the dots with a line by default (unless you deactivate the line). `scatter` doesn't join the points by default, and allows you to apply a different formatting for each data point (color, marker shape, etc...). Recommendation: if you do not need to differentiate the data points, use `plot`, if you need to display some points (of the same dataset) differently based on another property, then use `scatter`.

Comment: @Hoki Thanks for explaining the difference

Comment: Why a downvote ? did I miss something or didnt I show my own effort ? I just shared my observation and had a confusion or was there something untrue about the statement ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`plot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) has a concept of the order of the points mattering so you can use it to make line plots. `plot` also allows you to specify the input `x` and `y` values as either vectors or matrices or allows you to input multiple `x` and `y` vectors both of which allow you to plot multiple series at once:

[image: ![enter image description here]

whereas scatter only allows you to input 1 `x` and 1 `y` and they both have to be vectors. However, ['scatter'](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html) allows you to specify an area and colour vector to affect the points individually i.e.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you put the code of each graph? I will be so gratefull!

Comment: @AliRojas sorry I wrote this 4 years ago. But the code is trivial, look at https://matplotlib.org/gallery/shapes_and_collections/scatter.html#sphx-glr-gallery-shapes-and-collections-scatter-py for the last two and https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/simple_plot.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-simple-plot-py for the first one